# Definition of a branched 1-manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, graph-theory, dynamical-systems

i'm studying a papper which has this term "branched 1-manifolds", but the papper does not explain this, according to Wikipédia:

> "A finite graph whose edges are smoothly embedded arcs in a surface, such that all edges incident to a given vertex v have the same tangent line at v, is a branched one-manifold.  "

But i do not understand this definition. Someone could help me?

Comment: [Cross-posted to MO.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/218626/definition-o-branched-1-manifold)

Answer (score 3):

> A branched n-manifold is covered by n-dimensional "coordinate charts",
>   each of which involves one or several "branches" homeomorphically
>   projecting into the same differentiable n-disk in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branched_manifold

The finite graph case is just an example of a branched 1-manifold, **not the definition**.

Furthermore, they add a more specific example of such a graph, namely the figure of the number $8$ drawn on the plane.At the point where both circle intersect to give the "$8$", the 1-d curve describing it has one single tangent, yet in a neighborhood of it the second derivatives for each circle differ giving rise to two different branches -as see from the point of intersection.

Comment: You are welcome. That's what this site is for. I do have to make an observation: please, don't just simply change your question once you have an answer. At least keep the original one and amend it with any further insight/questions you may have after reading said answer. Otherwise it becomes a confusing Question/Answer set not much helpful. Worse, I be severely down-voted despite having help you. In brief, either keep your original question and amend it with the new one (write: "EDIT: According to Wikpedia...") or create a new question altogether.

Comment: I am a new member of the site, I'm still getting used to the good conduct here, thank you for the comments.

Comment: I'm so sorry @MASL

Comment: Don't be. There is no harm done. Most important thing of it all is willing to learn. And sometimes we do need others to help us do it.

Comment: Btw, once you feel satisfied with an answer you may accept and/or up-vote it, which is you way of saying it helped/solved your doubts. And Welcome to Math-Stackexchange!

Comment: I do not understand this part: 
     
"A finite graph whose edges are smoothly embedded arcs in a surface.." How i can see this formally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29271/discussion-between-c-junior-and-masl).

Comment: Answered you there.